# Prefilling Core Data for a read-only application

Tags: iphone, core-data

i am working on an application that displays read-only data i am shipping.
it is more of a book.

It is easy with SQLite but i am not satisfied with the performance and trying to use Core Data.

The issue is with pre-filling Core Data is that it is a hard process.

My question is:
Is it possible to build an assistant iphone application (for me to use) which uses the same data model for pre-filling.
and then take the populated .xcdatamodel file and use it in my original application?

I hope this makes sense :)

Adham

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're asking is whether you can create a CoreData database upfront and copy it to the iPhone.  Is that correct?

[This article](http://iphoneinaction.manning.com/iphone_in_action/2009/09/core-data-part-5-prefilling-data.html) will help.  Here's a quote:

I thus suggest the following five-step process:

1. Create your data in a comma-separated file, typically placing each row of data (an entity) in a row of the file and separating different columns (its attributes) by commas.
2. Write a standalone program and copy in your .xcdatamodel file from your main project.
3. Write code in your new program that parses your comma-separated file and inserts the information into a Core Data persistent store that should be identical to the persistent store in your main project.
4. Run the program in the Simulator
5. Copy your data from the Simulator's documents directory into your actual project's bundle.

Comment: Hi Benjamin
i have already read this page.
My question is:
can i use a stand alone program that is dedicated to filling CoreData database and after i enter the data, i copy the populated data file from the documents directory to my main bundle..

to rephrase:
can i replace the CVS file step with a standalone application for entering data?

Comment: Sure.  Just eliminate step 1.  Then replace step 3 with screens that allow you to insert the information yourself, rather than parsing any file for the data.  The Core Data file is the essence of it, and as long as your .xcodedatamodel file is identical between the projects you can copy the file and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, I've done it. I made a desktop application to read from a CSV file using the code here:

http://www.mac-developer-network.com/columns/coredata/may2009/

I just had to alter the way the CSV part worked, and change the model.

- I copied and pasted my model from the model builder into the iPhone model. (Clicked on the "grid" area, selected all, copied)
- Then I took the sqlite database the desktop app produced (found it in Application Support, in the folder for this application) and put it into the resources folder
- I made some code to copy the sqlite into the documents folder on the iPhone (if it wasn't already there) at startup, in the `applicationDidLaunch` method. It's possible that having it in the resources folder is no good. Even though you're using the database as read only, Core Data may want to write something to it. Not sure about this though..
- I used the sqlite file in the documents folder in my Core Data set up.

The desktop and iPhone Core Data sqlite file seem to be exactly the same format. You can transfer one sqlite file to another application (iPhone to iPhone too) as long as they have the same data model. In another application, I used NSXMLParser to create the Core Data sqlite file, then transferred it to another app, both on iPhone using the Simulator.

Comment: thank you too nevan.. this solution is a bit complicated for me as i am a newbie but you made the concept clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your data source can be whatever you want it to be.  The other suggestions are good ones.  Create a managed object model (.xcdatamodel) identical to what you want to use in your app.  Read in the data from your file, create a new instance of your managed object and populate it from the file.  Then save, and dive into the bundle in the iPhone Simulator and copy it over.  This has the added bonus of being in exactly the format you need, with all the helpful metadata.  Copy your object model and your managed object classes and you're good to go.

Note, though, if you really intend for it to be read-only, and you're using it at install, it will be installed in your finished app's bundle (under Applications/{SIGNATURE}/Myapp.app).  If you intend to edit this database or allow a user to save to it, it's a better idea to copy it to the Applications/{SIGNATURE}/Documents directory where your user database lives.