# Background Seeding/Loading iOS Core Data Store

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, core-data

My **iOS 8.0 +** app is essentially a dictionary app, presenting a read-only data set to the user in an indexed, easily navigable format.  I have explored several strategies for loading the static data, and I have decided to ship the app with several `JSON` data files that are serialized and loaded into a `Core Data` store once when the app is first opened.  The call to `managedObjectContext.save()`, therefore, will happen only once in the lifetime of the app, on first use.

From reading **Apple's** [`Core Data Programming Guide`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) in the **Mac Developer Library** (updated Sept. 2015), I understand that **Apple's** recommended practice is to 
1) separate the `Core Data` stack from the `AppDelegate` into a [`dedicated DataController object`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/IntegratingCoreData.html) (which makes it seem odd that even in **Xcode 7.2** the `Core Data` stack is still put in the `AppDelegate` by default, but anyway...); and 
2) open (and, I assume, seed/load) the persistent store in a [`background thread`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html) with a `dispatch_async` block, like so :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    //(get URL to persistent store here)

    do {
        try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)

        //presumably load the store from serialized JSON files here?
    } catch { fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)") }
}
```

I'm just getting started learning about concurrency and **GCD**, so my questions are basic:

1) If the data set is being loaded in a background thread, which could take some non-trivial time to complete, how does the initial `view controller` know when the data is finished loading so that it can fetch data from the `ManagedObjectContext` to display in a `UITableView` ?

2) Along similar lines, if I would like to test the completely loaded data set by running some fetches and printing debug text to the console, how will I know when the background process is finished and it's safe to start querying?

Thanks!

**p.s.** I am developing in **`swift`**, so any swift-specific tips would be tremendous.

Comment: @Hiren Please *do not* make trivial edits to posts that simply make words boldfaced, or make minimal changes to address the content of the post itself.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to make your app import the read-only data on first launch (forcing the user to wait while the data is imported), you can [import the data yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1719772/4151918), then add the read-only .sqlite file and data model to your app target, to be copied to the app bundle.

For the import, specify that the persistent store should use the rollback journaling option, since write-ahead logging is not recommended for read-only stores:

```
let importStoreOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [
    NSSQLitePragmasOption: ["journal_mode": "DELETE"],]
```

In the actual app, also specify that the bundled persistent store should use the read-only option:

```
let readOnlyStoreOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [
    NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption: true,
    NSSQLitePragmasOption: ["journal_mode": "DELETE"],]
```

Since the bundled persistent store is read-only, it can be accessed directly from the app bundle, and would not even need to be copied from the bundle to a user directory.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  For several reasons, I have decided to avoid a file-copy solution and to prefer a build-on-first-use solution.  For example, in a future version of the app, I may enable the user to write notes in the dictionary that would be persisted in the Core Data store.  Also, in a future version I may add an option to pull updated JSON files from the internet to "patch" the data store in place.  There are a couple other reasons, but in essence I am hoping to understand the async/background loading process better for now.

Comment: @vikingfo04 Your future intentions don't negate the possibility of pre-seeding the store before first launch.  You can simply bundle a writable store which can be migrated in a future app version.  Alternately, you can save notes in a separate store, whether or not you decide to update the dictionary store via URL.  Either way, you can still migrate and merge your data, but it would save you from having to also maintain code to initially import the data.

Comment: @vikingfo04 But to get back to your question, here are two reputable articles that discuss approaches for [importing data](https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data/) and [using Core Data in the background](https://www.objc.io/issues/2-concurrency/common-background-practices/).

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside whether loading a JSON at the first startup is the best option and that this question is four years old, the solution to your two questions is probably using notifications. They work from all threads and every listening class instance will be notified. Plus, you only need to add two lines:

1. The listener (your view controller or test class for question 2) needs to listen for notifications of a specific notification name:

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.handleMySeedNotification(_:)), name: "com.yourwebsite.MyCustomSeedNotificationName", object: nil)

where `@objc func handleMySeedNotification(_ notification: Notification)` is the function where you are going to implement whatever should happen when a notification is received.

2. The caller (your database logic) the sends the notification on successful data import. This looks like this:

   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "com.yourwebsite.MyCustomSeedNotificationName", object: nil)

This is enough. I personally like to use an extension to `Notification.Name` in order to access the names faster and to prevent typos. This is optional, but works like this:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let MyCustomName1 = Notification.Name("com.yourwebsite.MyCustomSeedNotificationName1")
    static let MyCustomName2 = Notification.Name("CustomNotificationName2")
}
```

Using them now becomes as easy as this: `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .MyCustomSeedNotificationName1, object: nil)` and even has code-completion after typing the dot!